# Superellipse on a square budget

Tags: mathematics

What’s better than an ordinary ellipse?
 
A
[*super* ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse),
of course.

And what’s better than a superellipse?
 
That’s right, a superellipse *and a square*.

But who can plot both of those luxury items?
 
Anyone, with a single function
you can make at home.

Here are
[implicit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function)
plots of
a superellipse,
two squares,
and a handy almost-superellipse loop.

[image]

$$\require{begingroup} \begingroup
   \def \K      { \kern-.5em }
    \def \p #1#2{ | {2 \over \large\raise.2ex\pi} #1 \kern.1em | ^ {#2} \! }
\begin{matrix}
&&&& \small\sf \rlap { In~the~lap~of~luxury } &&&
&&&&  \small\sf \rlap{ On~a~budget }
\\[2ex]
 \small\sf Loop &&&
  \large {\raise.2ex 1 \over 2\surd2} &\K   = &\K   f(x,y)
                                      & \K  = & \K   \p x{2.5} + \p y{2.5}
                                &&& 1 &  \K = &  \K h \, (x{+}y \, ,x{-}y)
\\[1ex]
 \small\sf Square &&&               1 &\K   = &\K   g(x,y)
                                      & \K  = & \K   \p x\infty + \p y\infty
                                &&& 0 &  \K = &  \K h \, (x{+}y \, ,x{-}y)
\end{matrix} \kern2em \\ \tiny\strut \endgroup$$

The status- conscious among us
may impress themselves by recognizing 
$ {\raise.2ex 1 \over 2\surd2} = f(x,y) $ 
as nothing less than a genuine superellipse,
yet the handy-dandy 
$\raise-.5ex\strut 1 = h \, (x{+}y \, ,x{-}y) $ 
is almost identical,
with 12 common points
and less than .011 of maximum separation.

Counting typographically,
$f(x,y)$ and
$g(x,y)$
are defined by **19** and **15** raw components, respectively,
including fraction lines, decimal points,
and everything else after the equals signs.

**Can you define
  $h(x,y)$
  with fewer than 10 raw components?**

The only components available are those
already present in the definitions of $f$ and $g$,
as well as
all other digits and constants,
along with
any other letters
as long as they spell out
trigonometric functions.
 
Every letter counts,
so, for example,
${ \small\raise .5ex \unicode {8220} } \kern-2mu \sin \kern-3mu
 {  \small\raise.5ex  \unicode{8221} }$
would contribute 3 components.

Both loops pass through
$( \pm  { \Large\pi \over \large 4 } ,
    \pm {  \Large\pi \over \large4 } )$
and the squares’ sides are at
$x = \pm  { \Large\pi \over \large 2 }$ and
$y =  \pm {  \Large\pi \over \large2 }$.
 
Portions of the
[Cartesian plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)
beyond the square
may contain other points and curves.
 
Never mind that $g(x,y)$
is defined casually and without regard to
the square’s vertices.

<sup>Online freebies that helped in preparation
and could help in solution:


[Function Grapher](http://functiongrapher.com)
– Good with explicit plots; no ads.


[MathGrapher at eMathHelp](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/online-graphing-calculator/)
– Good with implicit plots, sometimes bad with pop-up ads.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> $\cos~x + \cos~y$

Solution:

> Approximate the x and y intercepts of the loop as $\frac{\pi}{3}$ (since $2^{-\frac{8}{5}} \simeq \frac{1}{3.03}$). Then we need $h(\pm \frac{\pi}{3}, \pm \frac{\pi}{3}) = 1$, so to turn those $\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$s into something reasonable we probably need $\cos~x$ (there are other ways, of course, but it was hinted that we need trig and also it takes care of both positive and negative very compactly: $\cos~\frac{\pi}{3} = \cos~\frac{-\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$). It's likely to be symmetric in $x$ and $y$ so try out $\cos~x + \cos~y$ for now. We've got the loop; now to check what that looks like when $h = 0$ so we can modify it for the square and woah we're already done.

Answer (score 2):

**Non-solution** that may yet be of some interest:

If we write

> $h(u,v)=2-\cos u-\cos v$

then (exactly) the right thing happens at $h=0$ and we are within the necessary bounds at $h=1$. But the definition is, alas!, 11 symbols long.

[EDITED to add:]

D'oh. Actually the above is the result of a mis-conversion from my MATLAB fiddlings, and doesn't in fact do the right thing at $h=0$. If I do the conversion correctly, what I should have written before was

> $h(u,v)=\cos u+\cos v$

... but bmcfluff got there after the wrong version of my answer and before this correction. So it goes :-).

Comment: This is not a "non-solution" anymore but the an incredible virtual photo finish, within minutes (seconds?) after 3 days!